# Does crystallized silver conduct electricity better than amorphous silver?

Tags: conductors

Silver conducts electricity the best of all the common metals and metallic compounds.

Is there any advantage to using crystallized silver as a conductor? Do crystals of silver conduct better than amorphous silver?

Comment: You might have a hard time making pure amorphous silver. But, generally, amorphous metal alloys conduct worse than their crystalline counterparts. Too much scattering and localized states.

Comment: you'll probably get a lower resistance by annealing the silver (if it has been worked)  this trick works for copper. See also "metglas" which is amorphous metal and has reduced conductivity wrt polycrystaline alloys.

Comment: @Jasen - sure, but that works mainly because the alloys that can make metglas in the first place have fairly poor conductivities (relative to silver) to begin with. Silver is a near-perfect free-electron-like metal, and if pure you aren't going to get better than that.